# Google Cloud Build yaml docker environment variable

Tags: docker, environment-variables, google-cloud-build

I am trying to set an environment variable in a docker image via a cloudbuild.yaml for Google Cloud Build

Here is the sample cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
      - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
        args: ["run", "--rm", "--volume=/foo:/bar", "--privileged", "-e FOO=bar", "my/build:latest", "/root/init_build.sh" ]
timeout: "600s"
```

When I run on the command line locally and pass the environment variables into the container, it works as expected.  However, when I trigger a build in Cloud Build, the environment variable doesn't get set in the container.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the result I was looking for by doing the following:

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args: ["-c", "docker run --rm --volume=/workspace:/srv/jekyll --privileged -e FOO=bar my/build:latest /root/init_build.sh" ]
timeout: "600s"
```

Take a look at the [Docker commandline reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/) and [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161390/how-to-pass-parameters-to-docker-run-in-google-cloud-build) for more information

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).